# HBase Pseudo distributed or Fully distributed mode?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

I have a single linux(ubuntu) server in development environment and I plan to use a single server for production environment as well.

I have crawl data generated from Nutch 2.2.1 that I would like to store in HBase 0.90.6. Since, **I don't intend to use multiple machines**, (all I have is a single server) which mode of HBase is ideal for production env in my case - pseudo or fully-distributed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo distributed mode would be better as in Standalone mode local FS is used. This means you cannot take advantage of the parallelism provided by the HDFS+MR combo.

Comment: Thanks Tariq! I am slightly confused. Did you mean I can take advantage of the parallelism from HDFS+MapReduce if I use Pseudo distributed mode?

Comment: You will actually see some concurrency on a machine running pseudo cluster. The default setting is that a tasktracker can run up to two map and reduce tasks in parallel. Try increasing through **mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum** and **mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum** and see if makes any significant difference.

Comment: Thanks again! I will try that. My company client has provided us only one linux server for production environment, I don't see that to change in near future. Pseudo distributed mode is good enough for production environment? or will there be any need to migrate to a fully distributed mode? Note: I don't foresee using a cluster at all.

Comment: Not at all. I'm sorry to say, but your company has taken a wrong decision.

Comment: Unfortunately, we got to deal with that limitation. But let me tell you that I really don't have extreme volumes of data actually so I should be OKAY with one server I guess??? All I see is about may be 500,000 urls to store at the max in HBase on single node. What mode would you recommend for that requirement?

Comment: There is no harm in starting off with that. But you would definitely require more juice once your data and processing need go higher :)

Comment: Lol. Yes, I will get started with that! Thanks Tariq!

Comment: I have one last question. Which Hadoop version should I install for HBase 0.90.6 pseudo distributed mode to work?